# Subtracting of a python request

Tags: python, python-requests, http-headers

I am using python to send a **request** to an API in order to pull sensor data.

The **first request** that I am sending is to gauge the current time of the sensor.

The **second request** is to gauge the amount of time, since the sensor identified motion.

I am looking to **subtract** the first request, by the second.

Below is the method of pulling the data I am using, which works fine. I just cant figure out why it doesn't work when I try and subtract them.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
url = "IPADDRESS"
payload={}
headers = {
  "Authorization":"Password"
}
response1 = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)

print('Current Time: ', response1.text)


url = "IPAddress"
payload={}
headers = {
  "Authorization": "Password"
}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False) #HTTP request
print('Time since last motion: ', response.text)


updatedtime = response1.text
occupancelevel = response.text


result = updatedtime - occupancelevel

print(result)
```

Comment: Please don't bold every other word in your question, it **really** hurts **my** eyes ;)

Comment: Could you share the printed results?

Answer (score 0):

Subtraction only works with some datatypes. (Specifically, only objects which have a `.__sub__` method can be subtracted.)

I'm not sure what `.data` is, as per the docs it doesn't exist, but if it does it clearly isn't something subtractable.

If you are getting a simple number back from your endpoint, you can cast it first:

```py
response = float(response1.data) - float(response2.data)
```

Otherwise you are going to have to dig into what the response type *is*, and work accordingly.  (Hint: if you don't know, it's probably json.)

Incidentally if, as I think, there is no undeclared `.data`, you want `.text` or `.json()` to get at the response.

### References

https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response